# Print if col2 is greater than col2 in last line

Tags: awk

I want to use awk to extract line with greater column value than last line.

the sample data like that

```
a 3
a 5
a 4
b 1
c 2
c 3
c 6
```

I try to use below command, but not worked

```
awk '{if(($1!=a) || ($1==a && $2>b)){getline; print}};{a=$1;b=$2}'
```

the expected output:

```
a 3
a 5
b 1
c 2
c 3
c 6
```

only "a 4" line should be removed, because 4 is smaller than 2nd column of last line (5).

But the actual result from my code:

```
a 5
c 2
c 6
```

How can I resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Question: Why is the first line shown?

Comment: `last line` means the line at the end of the input. You meant `previous line`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one:

```
$ awk '$1!=p1 || $2>p2; {p1=$1;p2=$2}' file
a 3
a 5
b 1
c 2
c 3
c 6
```

*If `$1` changes or `$2` is greater from previous round, print*.

Generic solution for more fields, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786593/print-if-col2-is-greater-than-col2-in-last-line/58786671?noredirect=1#comment103884852_58786671) below.

Comment: Thanks. So the problem is the "getline" here which read the next line?

Comment: You could probably get it to work with `getline` but apparently I'm getting old as I look back rather than forward. :D Hmm, actually, with `getline` you read 2 lines on each iteration so it's probably not easy to handle.

Comment: Not a big deal when dealing with just 2 fields but to handle the general case of needing to access multiple fields from the previous line: `awk '$1!=p[1] || $2>p[2]; {split($0,p)}' file`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(when you are NOT looking for same 1st field value should be compared).

```
awk '$2>prev; {prev=$2}' Input_file
```

---

---

In case you want to look for same 1st field's comparisons with 2nd field values then try following.

```
awk 'prev_1st!=$1 || prev!=""; $2>prev && prev_1st==$1; {prev=$2;prev_1st=$1}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program here.
prev_1st!=$1 || prev!=""     ##Checking condition if prev_1st variable NOT equal to $1 OR variable prev is NULL then simply print the line.
$2>prev && prev_1st==$1      ##Checking condition if $2 is greater than prev AND prev_1st equals to $1 then print the line.
{
  prev=$2                    ##Creating variable prev and setting its value to $2.
  prev_1st=$1                ##Creating variable prev_1st and setting its value to $1.
}
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand well about "!prev;" here. And how can I add if condition with ";" in brackets?

Comment: @Bin, I have added detailed explanation for my code here. also IMHO using `getline` is not always reliable, so people usually perform making index like approaches.